# How can I store parse data into some variable

Tags: ios, json, swift

this is the code inside View.did() method

```
let myUrl = URL(string: "http://upegov.in:5002/api/AdbRegistrationNew");

var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)    
request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

let postString = "hello";

request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    // You can print out response object
    print("response = \(response)")

    //print out the response body

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    print("response data = \(responseString)")
    //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {

            // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
            var Otp = parseJSON["Otp"] as? String
            print(Otp!)

        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Response data output is

> response data = Optional([{"Msg":"1","Otp":"6359"}])**

Comment: i want to store OTP in some variable

Comment: You have it in a variable? `var Otp = parseJSON["Otp"] as? String`

Comment: Declare instance var like **var otp:String?** , then do **self.otp = parseJSON["Otp"] as? String**

Comment: I think he means he needs it in a variable which he can access somewhere else. Depending on this somewhere (scope), you would need to declare the variable at a different place.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yes sir you got it. ?? how can i Do it

Comment: http://upegov.in:5002/api/AdbRegistrationNew } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        26
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 14 Sep 2018 12:43:19 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "W/\"1a-c23vLg5m/FFMsR6M9gyk/srpFKY\""
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        Express
    );
} })
response data = Optional([{"Msg":"1","Otp":"6159"}])

Comment: The **ugliest** way to do it would be to declare the variable outside all the classes in any swift file. But if you have a specific place where you need to use it, a cleaner approach can be thought of like maybe delegation.

Comment: sir my api response is response data = Optional([{"Msg":"1","Otp":"6159"}])

Answer (score -1):

You can use Codable Protocol and create a variable of this model in your ViewModel and you can store this in CoreData/Realm storage or you can create a variable in singleton.

Create a stuct with Codable protocol

```
struct otpValueModel: Codable {
  let Msg: String?
  let Otp: String?
}

func sendRequest(completion : @escaping (( Data?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://upegov.in:5002/api/AdbRegistrationNew");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
    let postString = "hello";
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        completion(data, error)
    }
    task.resume()
}

func parseData(data: Data?, error: Error?, modelCompletion: @escaping (( [otpValueModel] ) -> Void)) {
    guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
            return
    }
    do {
        //here dataResponse received from a network request
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let models = try decoder.decode([otpValueModel].self, from:  dataResponse)
        modelCompletion(models)
    } catch let parsingError {
        print("Error", parsingError)
    }
}
```